# Problema al enviar variables desde arduino por metodo GET hacia pagina web

Tags: c, web, arduino, get

Tengo un problema con mi codigo en arduino, el cual consiste en enviar los valores de temperatura y humedad por el metodo GET desde el arduino a una pagina web.

Les comento, realice la decodificación del arduino para que enviar valores GET al servidor local de Xampp y se almacenaran las variables en una Base de Datos. Esto me funciona perfectamente en el servidor local.

Pero cuando subi los archivos de la pagina web al servidor, las variables GET que se envian desde el arduino, no las almacena en la Base de datos del servidor y desde el arduino (en el monitor serie) me informa que el envio de los datos es exitoso. Pero en la base de datos del servidor no se almacenan los datos.

Si Alguien me pudiese colaborar con este problema, quedo inmensamente agradecido. **Adjunto codigo del arduino cuando envia las variables al servidor por el metodo GET**

```
 
#include 
#include 
#include 
#include 

//Declara constantes y pin de entrada
#define DHTTYPE DHT22 //DHT21, DHT22, DHT11
#define DHTPIN 2  // El sensor de temperatura y humedad

// Ingresamos la direccion MAC para el controlador
byte mac[] = {  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress server(198, 54, 116, 181); //se tiene que modificar por obligacion la direccion IP de la maquina o servidor 198.54.116.181

// Inicializamos la Libreria de Ethernet Client
// con la dirección IP y el puerto del servidor
// con el que se quiere conetcar (el puerto 80 es el predeterminado para HTTP):
EthernetClient client; 

....

if (client.connect(server, 80)) { //colocar nombre de la página web sin http eso lo da el puerto 80

    float hum = dht.readHumidity(); //Leemos la Humedad
    float temp = dht.readTemperature(); //Leemos la temperatura en grados Celsius

    Serial.println("conectado"); 
    client.print("GET http://hector.paginaweb.click/secadero/controladores/conexion_arduino.php?temp="); // Enviamos los datos por GET para el servidor
    client.print(temp);
    client.print("&hum=");
    client.print(hum);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.0");
    client.println("User-Agent: Arduino 1.0");
    client.println();
    Serial.println("Envio con exito!");

    // Actualiza el tiempo en milisegundos de la ultima conexion
    ultimaConexion = millis();
}
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que dijito los valores manualmente, se ingresan a la base de datos. 

Le paso el enlace: 

http://hector.paginaweb.click/secadero/controladores/conexion_arduino.php?temp=25.2&hum=80.0 

Cuando esta asi, ingresa los datos a la Base de Datos, pero cuando esta de esta forma:

http://hector.paginaweb.click/secadero/controladores/conexion_arduino.php

Tendira que establecer la comunicacion desde el arduino con el servidor y decir el mismo mensaje, pero no es asi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El protocolo http es bastante estricto respecto al formato del mensaje.

En este caso en `GET` **no debe figurar** el servidor, sino la ruta del archivo... para indicar el servidor ya está el campo `Host`.

```
client.print("GET /secadero/controladores/conexion_arduino.php?temp="); // Enviamos los datos por GET para el servidor
client.print(temp);
client.print("&hum=");
client.println(hum)
client.println(" HTTP/1.0");
client.println("Host: hector.paginaweb.click");
client.println("User-Agent: Arduino 1.0");
client.println();
```

La cabecera final debería tener una forma similar a la siguiente:

```
GET /secadero/controladores/conexion_arduino.php?temp=.... HTTP/1.0
Host: hector.paginaweb.click
User-Agent: Arduino 1.0
[Linea sin contenido]
```

Por otro lado nunca estaría de más leer la respuesta del servidor para verificar que la comunicación es satisfactoria. Asumir que todo ha ido bien por el simple hecho de que has enviado el mensaje es mucho asumir.

Comment: eferion Muchas gracias he pdorbado el codigo tal cual como lo indicaste y ha funcionado. La verdad no tenia idea de lo estricto que es el protocolo http.

Muchas Gracias, Inmensamente Agradecido